# Booleans when generating NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios5

This feels like a super newb question, so apologizes in advance.

How does one specify booleans when using NSJSONSerialization?

My current code is below:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                            value, @"key",
                            NO, @"booleanKey",
                            nil];

NSData *jsondata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:0 error:nil];

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsondata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

It just seems to be ignoring it and the NSLog output looks like:

```
{"key":"THE VALUE OF id value"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that it is getting ignored is because `NO` is the same as `nil`, which terminates your dictionary list. You can only add objects into your dictionary, thus turn any primitive types into objects. E.g.: `NO` turns to `[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]` or if you are using Xcode 4.4 you can just use `@(NO)`.

Comment: Same question; this answer does not seem to work for me.  The result of @(NO) is an NSNumber equivalent to 0, which equates to an integer in JSON.  My intended result is to have a JSON boolean (ex: {"key":true}).  Any idea how to make that happen?

Comment: Just checked this and it works correctly and as you intend. What are you using to serialise the JSON object?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
[NSNumber numberWithBool: NO]
```

instead using the bool value directly.

You can check the doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html).